# How to set colspan to jquery datatable once column show hide function is called?

Tags: jquery, datatable, show, html-table, show-hide

I ma calling Jquery hide show function for column hiding , can anybody pls tell me how can i set colspan to table header ?

my function is as below
$(function () {

```
    $('.showHidecols').live('click', function () {

        var oTable = $('#searchTable').dataTable();

        iCol = $(this).val();

        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;

        oTable.fnSetColumnVis(iCol, bVis ? false : true);
    });
}
);
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
$('#header_cell_with_colspan').attr('colspan', bVis? 3: 2);
```